# MVP - Getting Data from the View to the Presenter

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I'm trying to get some practice implementing the MVP pattern in a simple C# WinForms application. On the left of the view is a tree view with a list of the files saved by the application; on the right of the view is a DataGridView for displaying whichever file is clicked in the tree view, or for typing into to save as a new file. The files are simply Dictionary objects written to disk with BinaryFormatter.

I created an interface for the view:

```
public interface IMappingsView
{
    event EventHandler SaveMapping;
    event EventHandler NewMapping;
    event EventHandler<DeleteArgs> DeleteMapping;
    event EventHandler PasteData;
    event EventHandler NodeClicked;
}
```

The delete button on the view has the following click event handler:

```
private void buttonDeleteMapping_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var node = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
    var args = new DeleteArgs(Path.Combine(RootDir,node));

    if (DeleteMapping != null)
    {
        DeleteMapping(this, args);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        RefreshTreeView();
    }
}
```

What is the best way to to pass information from the view to the presenter? I feel as though needing custom event arguments for every scenario is very wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the data you want available available via the interface as a property.

Assuming you have a firstName and lastName field that you want exposed...

```
public interface IMappingsView
{
    event EventHandler SaveMapping;
    event EventHandler NewMapping;
    event EventHandler<DeleteArgs> DeleteMapping;
    event EventHandler PasteData;
    event EventHandler NodeClicked;
    string FirstName {get;set;}
    string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your form that implements the interface,

```
string FirstName {
    get {
        return textFirstName.Text;
    }
    set { 
        textFirstName.Text = value;
    }
}
```

as an example.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Bush, that worked well. How would you approach getting data from the DataGridView in the Presenter?

Comment: Same basic approach.  Make the datasource you want to bind to a property in the form and interface.   The pattern is always the same, any method or property you need access to either to is defined in the interface and implemented in the form, regardless of datatype.